# Storing a geo route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geospatial, postgis, rails-postgresql

I'm planning to build a Rails application that should store data about a geo routes (potentially millions). The route is recorded from an smartphone or manually "drawn" in an web-interface.

A route consists of multiple (up to about 10.000) coordinates containing timestamp, latitude and longitude - but possible also altitude and accuracy.

When stored, I need to filter out "pgs noice", caluculate the total distance and show in on a map.

How would you suggest I store the route data?

I'm considering using PostgreSQL and would like each Trip to be stored in one row, for fast insertion and retrieval(?). This would require an multidimensional array field, which is only supported i Rails 4.0 (?).

At the same time, I have been looking at [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) and the [ActiveRecord Adapter](https://github.com/dazuma/activerecord-postgis-adapter), but are not sure if this is overkill or how it would work with an PostgreSQL array.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two options.

1. You could use an array of points on PostgreSQL.  Arrays in PostgreSQL are relatively complex and it is important to understand arrays and I the primary primitives primarily work on planes, not spheres so you lose spherical trig and the like.  For these reasons I don't really recommend this approach unless you are already familiar with both and have specific reasons to choose this one.  Of course you could also build your own spherical trig functions if you like....  But why you would when PostGIS is available I don't now.
2. You can use geography types in PostGIS.  These are helpful because you can store very complex multi-lines.  PostGIS gives you spherical trig capabilities too.  In general the types here are closer to what you are trying to do.

Finally I would recommend look at pgrouting which may give some additional functions you may find helpful.